# ubuntu dual boot on mac goes to black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, screen

I have been trying to dual boot Ubuntu on my 2009 Mac desktop running 10.10. The problem is it starts into refind, then I click on the cd and Ubuntu starts to load. It goes to a purple screen with a keyboard at the bottom then cuts to colored lines, then to black. I dont know why it is doing it? I know the download works as I am running inside virtualbox. It also does the same thing if I put in kali linux cd and try to run it live. It starts to boot gives me the ok ok, ok, then goes to colored lines and then black. I don't know if its graphics? or what??

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, its not a long term patch but it gets you there. It has something to do with the graphic card in the Mac desktop and the linux trying to run differently. So I installed kali-linux-2.0-amd64.iso as a dual boot. After reboot choose kali, in the boot menu. Then hole E key down, it comes to a blue kali screen. Mid way down there is a line that says "linux ..." (its long) go to the end of that line and enter nomodeset press ctrl x and it should boot with the log in screen appearing. Thank you guys for your help and hints!